# C# - To use Partial Classes, or Seperate Ones?

Tags: c#, class, partial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use partial classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601901/why-use-partial-classes)

Which way is best practice and the best programming approach, Partial Classes or Individual classes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Only use partial classes where there's a clear benefit in separating out the logic for one class into multiple files. The most obvious example is where some part of the code is autogenerated - code generators should usually build partial types, to allow for them to be augmented by the developer.

They can also be useful when refactoring one class into two, to get a feel of what the classes will look like afterwards.

Those are the major use cases really - I wouldn't start using them too liberally; it makes it harder to work out where everything is. Obviously there are exceptions... for example the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class in .NET 3.5 must be huge, and it would make sense to implement that with partial types to end up with manageable files.

Answer (score 3):

Partial classes are great for the differentiation between the GUI interface that is auto-generated, and the partial class that corresponds to that for YOUR code makes sure you and code which is auto-generated don't step on each other's toes.  Take advantage of that.

As for building your own custom classes / GUI controls, I would stay the same way.  Let the IDE help with the visual cosmetics, and the rest of the partial class to perform your custom functionality.