# EF6 Updating Model loses my Explicit Casts

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf

Entity framework seems to be almost more trouble than it is worth for larger databases.

In my apps (WCF Services, Hosts, and Clients) I need to synchronise various Entity Class Objects, have the Connection parameters in various app.config files (synchronised) and when I do a model update (Database to Code) Explicit Casts made in the models.cs are destroyed. This means a lot of time wasted re-writting code that has already been done.

The more complex this application / Database becomes the more unsuitable EF seems.

**How can I keep the Update Wizard undoing all my work, and keep things synchronised automatically?**

or should I just go back to Sql Commands?

Comment: Have you had a look into [T4 Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) in EF?

Comment: Yeah - didn't understand them at all :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change generated cs file ever, instead you should create partial classes to add your custom logic into generated classes. Have a look at [When is it appropriate to use C# partial classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601901/why-use-partial-classes), and similarly search google for more about partial classes in C#, you will get better idea of how to use them with your problem.