# In normal C# programming without designer.cs (UI), shall we use partial class? How shall we use it in this case?

Tags: partial-classes

I know the way to write a partial class in C# but i do not know **when to use it.** 
e.g. If i am not developing using Windows Form or UI in C#, how shall i start design my class?

**Java**: Class 
**C#**: Partial Class, Class

As above in C#, how shall we choose to use  **partial class** and **normal class** ( assume no UI element in the application) .

Comment: Look at that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601901/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-c-sharp-partial-classes

Comment: the question was closed and it is not the answer that i want. I am not asking how to implement it. I am focusing in when to use it. e.g for a simple app that haven grow, shall i start to use partial class instead?